# How to populate an arrayList with data collected through an object. (android)

Tags: java, android, date, arraylist, singleton

I am currently working on this problem in which I have to collect several data from input fields and save this as one instance in a list. So the idea is when I enter the data then click on the save button, all the data entered is gathered into an object which I will later store in the list. Among the data to be collected are a date, numbers from EditText fields and a string of characters from an EditText as well. The date and string of characters do not get copied from the EditText fields and when I try to collect data into an object it crashes at the first attempt. I'm also not sure how to use the collected data in the object with a singleton so I can populate the Arraylist.

XML:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bloodglucoselevelmonitor.BloodGlucoseLevelMonitor" >

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/afternoon"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/morning"
        android:layout_below="@+id/morning"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/afternoon"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/evening"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/afternoon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/afternoon"
        android:hint="@string/evening"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fasting"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/evening"
        android:layout_below="@+id/evening"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
        android:hint="@string/fasting"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fasting"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fasting"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/notes" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/morning"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/morning"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notes"
        android:text="@string/reset" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/history"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reset"
        android:text="@string/history" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/history"
        android:text="@string/save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save"
        android:text="@string/edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the .java file from which I try collecting the data:

```
package com.example.bloodglucoselevelmonitor;

import java.util.Date;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.example.bloodglucoselevelmonitor.R;



public class BloodGlucoseLevelMonitor extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_GLUCOSE_ID =      "com.example.bloodglucoselevelmonitor.glucose_id";
    Button reset, save, history;
    EditText morning, afternoon, evening, fasting, dailynotes;
    DatePicker date;
    GlucoseData collect;
    private GlucoseData mGlucoseData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_glucosedata);

      //activate listener for reset_button
            reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
              reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

      //clear text
                    EditText morning = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.morning);
                    EditText afternoon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.afternoon);
                    EditText evening = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.evening);
                    EditText fasting = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fasting);
                    EditText dailynotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes);
                        morning.setText("");
                        afternoon.setText("");
                        evening.setText("");
                        fasting.setText("");
                        dailynotes.setText("");
                    }
                    });

            save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    float morning_value=0;
                    float afternoon_value=0;
                    float evening_value=0;
                    float fasting_value=0;

                    EditText morning = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.morning);
                    EditText afternoon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.afternoon);
                    EditText evening = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.evening);
                    EditText fasting = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fasting);
                    DatePicker date = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
                    EditText dailynotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes);


                    //collect and convert all glucose readings.
                    String morning_string = morning.getText().toString();
                    morning_value = Float.parseFloat(morning_string);

                    String afternoon_string = afternoon.getText().toString();
                    afternoon_value = Float.parseFloat(afternoon_string);

                    String evening_string = evening.getText().toString();
                    evening_value = Float.parseFloat(evening_string);

                    String fasting_string = fasting.getText().toString();
                    fasting_value = Float.parseFloat(fasting_string);


                    collect.setMorningData(morning_value);
                    collect.setAfternoonData(afternoon_value);
                    collect.setEveningData(evening_value);
                    collect.setFastingData(fasting_value);
                    collect.setDate(date);
                    collect.setNotes(dailynotes);

                    //print appropriate message for each glucose reading.
                    if(morning_value < 70){
                        morning.setText("");
                        morning.setText(morning_value +": Hypoglycemic");
                    }else if(morning_value >140){
                        morning.setText(morning_value +": Abnormal");
                    }else if(morning_value >=70 && morning_value <= 140){
                        morning.setText(morning_value +": Normal");
                    }


                    if(afternoon_value < 70){
                        afternoon.setText("");
                        afternoon.setText(afternoon_value +": Hypoglycemic");
                    }else if(afternoon_value >140){
                        afternoon.setText(afternoon_value +": Abnormal");
                    }else if(afternoon_value >=70 && afternoon_value <= 140){
                        afternoon.setText(afternoon_value +": Normal");
                    }



                    if(evening_value < 70){
                        evening.setText("");
                        evening.setText(evening_value +": Hypoglycemic");
                    }else if(evening_value >140){
                        evening.setText(evening_value +": Abnormal");
                    }else if(evening_value >=70 && evening_value <= 140){
                        evening.setText(evening_value +": Normal");
                    }


                    if(fasting_value > 70 && fasting_value < 99){
                        fasting.setText("");
                        fasting.setText(fasting_value +": Normal");
                    }else{
                        fasting.setText("");
                        fasting.setText(fasting_value +": Abnormal");
                    }

                }


                });

            history = (Button) findViewById(R.id.history);

            history.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(BloodGlucoseLevelMonitor.this, GlucoseListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
            }

            });             


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.blood_glucose_level_monitor, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The next java file contains the object type which which I try to use above in collecting the data from the EditText Fields:

```
    package com.example.bloodglucoselevelmonitor;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class GlucoseData {

        private UUID mId;
        private String mTitle;
        private float morningData, afternoonData, eveningData, fastingData;
        private DatePicker mDate;
        private EditText notes;

        public GlucoseData() {

            mId = UUID.randomUUID();

        }

        public UUID getId() {
            return mId;
        }

        public void setId(UUID id) {
            mId = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            mTitle = title;
        }

        public float getMorningData() {
            return morningData;
        }

        public void setMorningData(float morningData) {
            this.morningData = morningData;
        }

        public float getAfternoonData() {
            return afternoonData;
        }

        public void setAfternoonData(float afternoonData) {
            this.afternoonData = afternoonData;
        }

        public float getEveningData() {
            return eveningData;
        }

        public void setEveningData(float eveningData) {
            this.eveningData = eveningData;
        }

        public float getFastingData() {
            return fastingData;
        }

        public void setFastingData(float fastingData) {
            this.fastingData = fastingData;
        }

        public DatePicker getDate() {
            return mDate;
        }

        public void setDate(DatePicker date) {
            mDate = date;
        }

        public EditText getNotes() {
            return notes;
        }

        public void setNotes(EditText notes) {
            this.notes = notes;
        }





    }
```

Finally, the singleton:

```
    package com.example.bloodglucoselevelmonitor;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import android.content.Context;

    public class GlucoseLab {

        private ArrayList<GlucoseData> mGlucose;

        private static GlucoseLab sGlucoseLab;
        private Context mAppContext;

        public void add(GlucoseData collect){
            mGlucose.add(collect);


        }


        private GlucoseLab(Context appContext){

            mAppContext = appContext;
            mGlucose = new ArrayList<GlucoseData>();

    //use object to populate array List



        }

        private Context getActivity() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }


        public static GlucoseLab get(Context c) {
            if(sGlucoseLab == null){
                sGlucoseLab = new GlucoseLab(c.getApplicationContext());
            }
            return sGlucoseLab;

        }

        public ArrayList<GlucoseData>getGlucose(){
            return mGlucose;
        }
        public GlucoseData getGlucoseData(UUID id){
            for(GlucoseData c : mGlucose){
                if(c.getId().equals(id))
                    return c;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Here's what I get from the LogCat:

```
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at com.example.bloodglucoselevelmonitor.BloodGlucoseLevelMonitor$2.onClick(BloodGlucoseLevelMonitor.java:88)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-03 21:24:26.303: E/AndroidRuntime(21478):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 21:24:28.503: I/Process(21478): Sending signal. PID: 21478 SIG: 9
```

Any help on how to solve these problems will be appreciated. If there's need for any more information, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: you talk about the crash and yet you don't post the crash report.

Comment: @Olayinka thanks for the reply, I just updated the question with the LogCat report.

Answer (score 1):

In the class/activity `BloodGlucoseLevelMonitor` you accessed a valiable `collect` that wasn't initialized.